# Why does one type guard work and the others don't, including a type guard function

Tags: typescript, typeguards

I'm not sure why the type guard function, and assigning a value to a variable don't work as type guards in the following examples.

Can someone point me to why this is?

```
interface UserData {
  personalInfo?: {
    name: string;
  }
}

const isUserData = (i: any): i is UserData => {
  // This is fine for our example
  return true;
};

const user: UserData = {
  personalInfo: {
    name: `Joe`,
  }
}

/*
name could be:
 - undefined: personalInfo is undefined
 - string: user.personalInfo is defined, and name is a string
*/
const usersName = user.personalInfo?.name;

if (usersName) {
  // inside this conditional we know that name is a string,
  // and that it isn't a falsy string ("")
  // Why doesn't this work??
  // TS error "user.personalInfo is possibly undefined"
  const newString:string = user.personalInfo.name;
}

// A type guard function doesn't work
if (isUserData(usersName)) {
  // TS error "user.personalInfo is possibly undefined"
  const newString: string = user.personalInfo.name;
}

// However if we use the variable directly, it works
if (user.personalInfo?.name) {
  // No TS error.
  const newString: string = user.personalInfo.name;
}

// This also works (as expected)
if (!!user.personalInfo?.name) {
  // No TS error.
  const newString: string = user.personalInfo.name;
}
```

Comment: For most of these the short answer is as given in [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/41926#issuecomment-742879302); TypeScript [narrowing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html) only happens for particular common syntactic constructs that have been explicitly implemented. It does not derive every possible logical consequence of control flow, because that would be enormously expensive and programs would never finish type checking. Does that fully address the question? If so I could write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz Yes please do

Comment: Okay I will do so when I get a chance (might be 11-12 hours from now)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Type [narrowing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html) in TypeScript only happens in particular situations that have been specifically implemented to have this effect.  The narrowing support is, in essence, a series of heuristic rules that do useful things in many circumstances.  It is not a full analysis of every possible logical implication of every relationship between values.

According to [a comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/41926#issuecomment-742879302) by the TS team development lead on a similar narrowing issue, [microsoft/TypeScript#41926](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/41926):

> Control flow narrowing works based on looking for syntax that applies to the variable in question. In this example, nothing *directly* seems to influence `value`, so it has its unnarrowed type.
>
> We don't have the performance budget to do the sort of whole-universe counterfactual analysis that would be required to correctly detect this pattern.

---

The direct [truthiness](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#truthiness-narrowing) check of a nested property via [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) narrows the type of that property, because this behavior was directly implemented for that in [microsoft/TypeScript#33821](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/33821).  So this works:

```
if (user.personalInfo?.name) {
  const newString: string = user.personalInfo.name;
}

if (!!user.personalInfo?.name) {
  const newString: string = user.personalInfo.name;
}
```

But the checks performed on an aliased *copy* of the nested property does *not* narrow that property, because such narrowing was never implemented. Presumably it would be too difficult to do this because then every copied value would have to potentially trigger huge amounts of extra analysis work.

But maybe someday in the future, if enough people request it, it could be implemented.  After all, something similar has already happened; and there is some support for [control flow analysis of aliased conditions and discriminants](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-4.html#control-flow-analysis-of-aliased-conditions-and-discriminants).  So perhaps there's hope? But ultimately such heuristic analysis will never be able to anticipate every possible developer use case, so there will always be code that a human being can see is correct but the compiler does not.  Your choices then are to refactor to a version which the compiler understands, or to use something like a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to tell the compiler that you are smarter than it is:

```
if (usersName) {
    const newString: string = user.personalInfo!.name; // <-- assert
}
```

The [non-null assertion operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#non-null-assertion-operator-postfix-) there is you just telling the compiler not to worry about the nullish possibility and that *you* have verified the correctness.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKoGdoBE5jsgbwChlTkAHadAexDgBsBJEGagfgC5CSze6BbCF3RgooAOYBuHqQC+ReUQS0RyYOgzZc+ALzIAFMC5wQATwCUXYGvRpMUHHmQ6AfN14B6D8gAqAC3UbZBhQFFYoZGoAVwiIAA84fnJ6CBlkKAgwGJBkUSiIaVlpJRUwZCj7Lk0HbWd3MkooGjomFmouYl4+RKFkAAMAKWoIPoAaNPlFDwAqIgEUZSj6ABNkACMhEgBacpBliBCQCGWuRuaGZlYgqL2D0OXt5BExEHEuCugAOjPaC7ag-aHY6jZAmVbzIL4Z4SIjTDwlECqD5NAByPTqyO+VF+rVYbE+82KwBgBmR6DRgnM9VIykRZSOAHcAMqiCTCVmvDH2LFNHGXagAQgJPUKRCIXmQAEFcqZKMhxFE4FBVjAbggwMBaMhlsN0CAAORlBnUKAAayIxIM6mqjjg+jJFIg5ipnTItNUjJZLzeTw54i5Xx+LX5QsJCjFEoAEtQGRAAG7QNQk2PlTC5PwoONK4BwNYpbXADLq+imEHAI0m03oC0k+3coN-PHCynU5ASlHUXxM5DQKAmz5pd30iDMv3s70BqA88646jNgrh8XefyBBg0ZDGs22fRwWzxSjq47mGsGAUCzEN2f4+YutLtzs+bu9-uD0rIT1j30TvQX7HBtrzqKYpAA)

Answer (score 0):

The `if` uses the intermediate variable `usersName`, but inside the condition the initial variable `user.personalInfo.name` is used, so Typescript can't assure that the value hasn't changed in between.

For example:

```
const usersName = user.personalInfo?.name;

user.personalInfo = undefined; // reassign a value to user.personalInfo

if (usersName) {
  // here, usersName is not undefined
  // but user.personalInfo is, because it was reassigned above
  const newString: string = user.personalInfo.name;
}
```

But this works, because inside the `if`, Typescript knows for sure that `usersName` is defined.

```
const usersName = user.personalInfo?.name;

user.personalInfo = undefined; // reassign a value to user.personalInfo

if (usersName) {
  // here, usersName is not undefined, you can assign its value to a string
  const newString: string = usersName;
}
```

Comment: Oh I see! It's because `usersName` is a primitive and not a reference to the object. In spite of this, I'm surprised that TS can't understand that the object isn't modified between when `usersName` is created and when it's used as a type guard.

Comment: I think it would behave the same with a reference type. Typescript does static type checking, it doesn't evaluate the code to see if a variable is modified or not. The best it can do is assuring that `usersName` is not `undefined` when used inside a `if (usersName)` block.